# How to clone github repository to particular folder of hosting without Repository name?

Tags: github, git-clone

I have my repository on git and it works fine. Repository name is say XXX. Now when i goto my hosting service by connection with SSH and try to clone code with "**git clone URL**" command in my public_html/ folder, it creates **public_html/XXX/**. Is there any way by which i can directly get my whole code at public_html/ ?

Comment: `git clone <URL> <directory>` Try `git help <command>` (e.g. [`git help clone`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone)) next time, or even just Google.

Comment: i tried that but as it has cgi-bin folder it do not allowed me.

Comment: Git has no special treatment of directories named `cgi-bin` so without more information than that there's nothing I can say.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could cut your files inside XXX along with the .git file and paste onto your public_html/ folder. Or simply put a . `git clone URL .`